# BroadcastReceiver does not work when app is closed forcefully or removed from the recent apps list

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I have created a Broadcast Receiver that listens for incoming messages. I have registered it in the manifest and tested it, and it is working fine.

**But the problem is that it stops working when the app is closed forcefully by the user i.e. when it is removed from the recent apps list by the user.**

I have read that by doing so the app gets to the stopped state and will not receive any broadcast until it is again started by the user.

**How do I create a broadcast receiver that is always listening i.e. even if the app is closed forcefully/removed from the recent apps list.**

Do I need to create a service and use that to register or listen to the broadcasts? Or there is any other way to do this?

Comment: you should use service instead of BroadCastReceiver

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create service for that and write exclude from recent tag in manifest.